# Lua Raw Socket Example

Tags: sockets, network-programming, lua

I'm having a hard time finding some example code for Raw Sockets in Lua. Ideally they should look something like they do in Python:

```
#create a raw socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

# tell kernel not to put in headers, since we are providing it, when using IPPROTO_RAW this is not necessary
# s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# now start constructing the packet
packet = '';

source_ip = '192.168.1.101'
dest_ip = '127.0.0.1' # or socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')

# ip header fields
ip_ihl = 5
ip_ver = 4
ip_tos = 0
ip_tot_len = 0  # kernel will fill the correct total length
ip_id = 54321   #Id of this packet
ip_frag_off = 0
ip_ttl = 255
ip_proto = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
ip_check = 0    # kernel will fill the correct checksum
ip_saddr = socket.inet_aton ( source_ip )   #Spoof the source ip address if you want to
ip_daddr = socket.inet_aton ( dest_ip )

ip_ihl_ver = (ip_ver << 4) + ip_ihl

# the ! in the pack format string means network order
ip_header = pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_ihl_ver, ip_tos, ip_tot_len, ip_id, ip_frag_off, ip_ttl, ip_proto, ip_check, ip_saddr, ip_daddr)

# tcp header fields
tcp_source = 1234   # source port
tcp_dest = 80   # destination port
tcp_seq = 454
tcp_ack_seq = 0
tcp_doff = 5    #4 bit field, size of tcp header, 5 * 4 = 20 bytes
#tcp flags
tcp_fin = 0
tcp_syn = 1
tcp_rst = 0
tcp_psh = 0
tcp_ack = 0
tcp_urg = 0
tcp_window = socket.htons (5840)    #   maximum allowed window size
tcp_check = 0
tcp_urg_ptr = 0

tcp_offset_res = (tcp_doff << 4) + 0
tcp_flags = tcp_fin + (tcp_syn << 1) + (tcp_rst << 2) + (tcp_psh <<3) + (tcp_ack << 4) + (tcp_urg << 5)

# the ! in the pack format string means network order
tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_source, tcp_dest, tcp_seq, tcp_ack_seq, tcp_offset_res, tcp_flags,  tcp_window, tcp_check, tcp_urg_ptr)

user_data = 'Hello, how are you'
```

If you guyshave some laying around or know where to find some. I haven't seen much from my google searching.

Thanks,

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? you could check out [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/home.html) to see if that meets your needs.

Comment: LuaSocket doesn't have much functionality in terms of parsing or creating headers. I need to beable to create my own IP/TCP/UDP headers for testing purposes. I was hoping someone would know where to find a library for raw sockets for Lua or if there was some way to do it with the existing Lua Socket Library. The documentation on Luasocket is very simple and doesn't go into much detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaSocket is not made for this. Maybe look at [libpcap](https://github.com/sam-github/pcap-lua) and [libnet](https://github.com/sam-github/libnet)?